# Why .NET RESTful API can load DLLs on development machine but not on other (AWS EC2) machine?

Tags: .net, rest, dll, ibm-midrange

I am building a .NET (4.6.1) RESTful API (on winx64 OS) and its working fine on my development, but when I copy the service binary on other (win64 OS) machine it fails on the lines where I try to make use of these binaries to which I referenced (i.e. to crate a class instance/object). To be precise I am referencing IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll in my project. This binary is part of IBM Client access software and this software is installed (hence the binary is also on exact same path on both machines).

I have tried compiling the code on the machine the code is failing, I am using MSBuild.exe to get that done, but of no use, facing same issue.

Following is the stack-trace of the error I am getting.

*`{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The type initializer for 'IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Constants' threw an exception.","exceptionType":"System.TypeInitializationException","stackTrace":"   at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Connection.InitializeDefaultProperties()\r\n   at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Connection..ctor(String connectionString)\r\n   at tractelsyncrestapi.Helpers.AS400Helper.ExecuteProcedureNoParam(String procName, String libraryName) in C:\\Sandbox\\tractelsyncrestapi\\tractelsyncrestapi\\Helpers\\AS400Helper.cs:line 186\r\n   at tractelsyncrestapi.Controllers.InventoryController.GetInventoryDataFromAS400(Boolean onlyNewData) in C:\\Sandbox\\tractelsyncrestapi\\tractelsyncrestapi\\Controllers\\InventoryController.cs:line 59\r\n   at tractelsyncrestapi.Controllers.InventoryController.Get() in C:\\Sandbox\\tractelsyncrestapi\\tractelsyncrestapi\\Controllers\\InventoryController.cs:line 98\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()","innerException":{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The provider cannot run in 64-bit mode.","exceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException","stackTrace":"   at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Constants..cctor()"}}`*

Comment: seems to be a well known problem : https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/64-bit-net-provider-iseries. Do you have the exact same version of the IBM client on both environments ?

Comment: No, I don't. But I have tried replacing the relevant binary on my target machine with the one on my machine, but of no use. Also my other CLI is using again same development machine to build CLI and that CLI is again using same binary and doing similar thing and when ported on the same target machine, it works. So this rules out the binary mismatch issue i presume. Anyways thanks a lot for taking time to answer, help is very much appreciated. @B.Lec